# Rで組み分けをその中から特定の項目をカウントしたいのですが

Tags: r

組  得意科目
1  A    国語
2  A    数学
3  B    国語
4  C    数学
5  C    数学
6  C    国語
7  C    国語

このような表から国語が得意な人間の数を組ごとに出したいのですが、

A １
B １
C ２

のような形で回答が出るようにしたいです。
どのように書けばよいでしょうか。

Comment: `B 0` ではなく、`B 1` ではないでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。訂正しました。

Comment: `aggregate` でグルーピングするのはどうでしょうか。`setNames(aggregate(df$得意科目, list(df$組), FUN=function(x){length(x[x=='国語'])}), c('組', '国語が得意科目の人数'))`

Comment: 参考になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` を使って

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(得意科目 == '国語')　%>%
    group_by(学級) %>% summarize(Count = n())
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#     学級 Count
#   <fctr> <int>
# 1      A     1
# 2      B     1
# 3      C     2
```

でどうでしょうか

Comment: やってみてうまくいきましたありがとうございます。